# NSApplication menubar does not respond as expected in nib-less Cocoa application

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have the following single file of code, in which I'm trying to create a Cocoa application with basic functionality in as little code as possible without using nibs or Xcode. I have been getting most of my information from the following blog post, in which the equivalent Objective-C code has been posted: (http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html). The only major change that I have made is an AppDelegate class to manage the window, which is typically what is done in Xcode projects.

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var window: NSWindow

    override init() {
        self.window = NSWindow()
        self.window.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1280, height: 720), display: true)
        self.window.collectionBehavior = .FullScreenPrimary
        self.window.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask
        self.window.title = "Main Window"
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(notification: NSNotification) {
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    }

    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

autoreleasepool {
    NSApplication.sharedApplication()
    NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.Regular)

    let delegate = AppDelegate()
    NSApp.delegate = delegate

    let mainMenu = NSMenu()
    NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu

    let applicationMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
    mainMenu.addItem(applicationMenuItem)

    let applicationMenu = NSMenu()

    let quitMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
    quitMenuItem.action = #selector(NSApp.terminate(_:))
    quitMenuItem.keyEquivalent = "q"
    quitMenuItem.title = "Quit Cocoa Window Test"
    applicationMenu.addItem(quitMenuItem)

    applicationMenuItem.submenu = applicationMenu

    NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
    NSApp.run()
}
```

I successfully compile from Terminal with the following command:

```
swiftc -o bin/CocoaWindowTest -g -framework Cocoa ./src/main.swift
```

My issue arises with the menu. Although the ⌘Q keyboard shortcut works as expected, the application menu that I've created won't open, and I haven't been able to figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by calling `NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps()` after `NSApp.run()` has already been called. To summarize, the main segment of my code now reads something like this:

```
autoreleasepool {
    NSApplication.sharedApplication()
    NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.Regular)

    let delegate = AppDelegate()
    NSApp.delegate = delegate

    // Menu setup here...

    NSApp.run()

    NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mainMenu.setSubmenu(applicationMenu, forItem:applicationMenuItem)` to set the submenu. Items with submenus have a special action, `submenuAction(_:)`, assigned, which is responsible for actually showing the submenu. The above method properly assigns that action (and is preferred to setting it yourself).

For what it's worth, I wouldn't set `NSApp.mainMenu` until the menu is complete.

Comment: Changing `applicationMenuItem.submenu = applicationMenu` to `mainMenu.setSubmenu(applicationMenu, forItem:applicationMenuItem)` as you've suggested works. However, as it turns out, my original code also has the same working behavior. It turns out my bug was actually that the window must be deactivated for another app and then reactivated for the menu to begin working. So now my question would be: "How I can get the menu to update automatically without needing to switch to another app?"

Comment: How about not changing the activation policy until after the menu is installed?